# How to sum two virtual column into third column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

here i attached file first two columns is fine i want sum of `completed_hours` + `Registered_hours` into `total_credit_hours`.

[image]

Note: First Two columns are virtual columns.

Here View Structure;

`STDCODE    VARCHAR2(20)
ALTCODE VARCHAR2(15)
NAME    VARCHAR2(50)
ADMDATE DATE
DEGREE_CODE VARCHAR2(10)
SEM_CODE    VARCHAR2(20)
SECCORSCODE VARCHAR2(10)
ID  VARCHAR2(15)
CNAME   VARCHAR2(50)
INSTRUCTOR  VARCHAR2(50)
TIMETABLE   VARCHAR2(200)
GRADES  VARCHAR2(2)
MARKS   NUMBER(6,2)
CRHRS   NUMBER(10,2)`

**and Query is here**

```
select distinct altcode,name,
(
SELECT sum(CRHRS)
      FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
      WHERE grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

    ) as completed_credit_hours,
    (select sum(CRHRS)
      from V_ALLSTUDATA b
       where grades is null  and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

    ) as registerd_credit_hours
   ,
    ( select sum(CRHRS) 
    from V_ALLSTUDATA b
    where grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+',null) and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

    ) as Total_credits_hours

from V_ALLSTUDATA a
where sem_code like'%FALL-19%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select altcode,name,completed_credit_hours,registerd_credit_hours,sum(completed_credit_hours+registerd_credit_hours) over( partition by altcode,name) as total_credit_hours
        from  (                   
                select distinct altcode as altcode,name as name,
                (
                SELECT sum(CRHRS)
                      FROM V_ALLSTUDATA b
                      WHERE grades in ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

                    ) as completed_credit_hours,
                    (select sum(CRHRS)
                      from V_ALLSTUDATA b
                       where grades is null  and a.name = b.name and a.altcode= b.altcode

                    ) as registerd_credit_hours

                from V_ALLSTUDATA a
                where sem_code like'%FALL-19%'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the first 2 columns and then sum them to obtain the third one. I'd use [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) for that :

```
WITH my_cte AS (
  SELECT altcode,
         name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN grades IN ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') THEN CRHRS ELSE 0 END) AS completed_credit_hours,
         SUM(CASE WHEN grades is NULL  THEN CRHRS ELSE 0 END) AS registerd_credit_hours
  FROM   V_ALLSTUDATA a
  WHERE  sem_code LIKE '%FALL-19%'
  GROUP BY altcode, name
);

SELECT  altcode,
        name,
        completed_credit_hours,
        registerd_credit_hours,
        (completed_credit_hours + registerd_credit_hours) AS Total_credits_hours
FROM    my_cte;
```

Comment: its error showing in this line  SUM(CASE WHEN grades IN ('A','A+','B','B+','C','C+','D','D+') THEN CRHRS ELSE O END) AS completed_credit_hours,             ORA-00904: "O": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifie

Comment: It's `0` not `O`