# Rails calculating a virtual column using 2 other virtual columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-7

I need help converting the following MySQL query into an ActiveRecord Query that will produce a relation with IP records as object.
To explain this in a better way, How to convert the following query in [How to sum two virtual column into third column in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087041/how-to-sum-two-virtual-column-into-third-column-in-sql) in ActiveRecord query ?

```sql
select a_id
u_c,
i_c,
(u_c + i_c) as t_c
from (
    select distinct a.id as a_id,
    (   SELECT count(b.id) FROM UP b
        WHERE b.i_p_id = a.id
        AND b.role = "L"
    ) as u_c,
    (   SELECT count(b.id) from UP b
        WHERE b.institution_package_id = a.id
        AND b.role = "I"
    ) as i_c
    from IP a
    left outer join UP b on b.IP = a.id       
) sub
```

Let me explain a litte more.
I have 2 tables where I am querying into the 1st table and calculating 3 virtual columns.
The 3rd column will be the sum of the other 2 virtual columns.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You already have the SQL you want -- make it a view and create an ActiveRecord class based on it,.

Comment: Whenever you have a complex SQL query that might not be easily implemented with ActiveRecord, you can take advantage of Arel (check out this [guide](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/creating-advanced-active-record-db-queries-arel) ). It's not really meant to be used directly but many people use it because it is really powerful tool(which is actually what's under the hood of ActiveRecord).

Comment: if this is a query written by somebody else, be aware that this type of query in a rails app usually means that the ActiveRecord implementation was too difficult, too inefficient, and too slow.

Comment: It's not very easy to understand such small var names , did you design your tables with rails ? 
Ithink there is a pb in the base design inside your rails app if you're in need of such contraptions in sql . 
Can you show your models and explain the use case . 
Or if you dont want explain you can use :

`sql = "Select * from ... your sql query here"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end I went with the raw query execution. I was trying to preserve the ActiveRecord relation, thats why was about an activerecord query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing complicated queries in SQL and executing them via rails is a simple, okay, and often the shorter solution.

But if you actually want to use Rails tools for reusability and/or security purposes, then this query CAN be achieved via Arel, which is the tool that ActiveRecord queries are built on internally.

This is considered private api and is subject to change. Use caution when upgrading rails.

```rb
class IP < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ups, foreign_key: :IP, class_name: 'UP'
end
class UP < ActiveRecord::Base
end


a = IP.arel_table.alias('a')
b = UP.arel_table.alias('b')

first_subquery = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    UP.from(b).where(
      b[:i_p_id].eq(a[:id]).and(b[:role].eq('L'))
    ).select(b[:id].count).arel
)
second_subquery = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    UP.from(b).where(
      b[:institution_package_id].eq(a[:id]).and(b[:role].eq('I'))
    ).select(b[:id].count).arel
)
sub = IP.left_joins(:ups).distinct.select(
  a[:id].as('a_id'),
  first_subquery.as('u_c')
  second_subquery.as('i_c')
).arel.as('sub')

Arel::SelectManager.new.from(sub).project(
  sub[:a_id],
  sub[:u_c],
  sub[:i_c],
  (sub[:u_c] + sub[:i_c]).as('t_c')
).to_sql
```

It will produce something like this

```sql
SELECT sub."a_id",
    sub."u_c",
    sub."i_c",
    (sub."u_c" + sub."i_c") AS t_c
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT "a"."id" AS a_id,
            (
                (
                    SELECT COUNT("b"."id")
                    FROM "UP" "b"
                    WHERE "b"."i_p_id" = "a"."id"
                        AND "b"."role" = 'L'
                )
            ) AS u_c,
            (
                (
                    SELECT COUNT("b"."id")
                    FROM "UP" "b"
                    WHERE "b"."institution_package_id" = "a"."id"
                        AND "b"."role" = 'I'
                )
            ) AS i_c
        FROM "IP"
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "UP" ON "UP"."IP" = "IP"."id"
    ) sub;
```

I added several aliases to make it similar to the initial query, but since Arel is taking care of referencing them, most aliases can just be removed.